# Rails 4 ActiveRecord group_by and nested loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, nested-loops, rake-task

The project I am working on has the following models:

- Button: has many extra_prices (one for each Currency)
- ExtraPrice: belongs to a product (in that case a Button) and has as an attribute a currency_id
- Currency: there is a reference to a currency_id on an ExtraPrice as I mentioned above. FYI there are 4 currencies so far in the app.

Some of the buttons don't have an extra_price set in one of the currencies which causes an error in another part of the app.

I am trying to write a rake task that would:
- check all buttons missing an extra_price for one a more currencies
- find out which currency is missing
- create the extra price

So far I toyed with a few options but I am stuck (I am pretty junior as a dev, and especially on the back-end side/DB query).

I was thinking something like:

```
Button.transaction do
  currencies = Currency.all.pluck :id    

  buttons_no_extra_price = Button.select { |button| button.extra_prices.length < 
  currencies.length }
end
```

and then I'm stuck :)

I would like to do something like

```
buttons_no_extra_price.group_by(|button| button.extra_prices.currency_ids) 

(wrong formatting of course since extra_prices is an array and currency_id is an attribute on each extra_price)
```

but instead of grouping them by currency_id, I would like to group them by the missing currency_id or ids, maybe using the currencies variable above.

```
missing_prices = {currency1: [button1, button2], currency2: [button192, button208], currency3: [button392, button220]...}
```

This way I could loop through every Currency and create an extra_price on each button object of the nested array like:

```
missing_prices.each |currency, array_of_buttons| do 
  array_of_buttons.each do |button|
    ExtraPrice.create!(currency: currency, product: button)
  end
end
```

I am also thinking that from a performance standpoint it needs to be optimized so maybe work more with includes, joins, etc. but it's a bit above my current abilities to be totally honest.

So any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Not a big deal, but in the future I would post the relationships in your models with code instead of writing it out in a sentence. Makes it a bit easier to understand. Just thought I'd mention it. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Is currency an ActiveRecord or an ActiveModel? That is, is there a `currencies` table?

Comment: Thanks Dylan, you are right I should have posted the actual model.rb structure. Would have been clearer.

Comment: @Schwern there is an currencies table. thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I follow your question, and if I am this should do the trick. Let me know if you have any questions. Note that there is probably a more performant way to do this, but given that it's a rake task performance won't need to be fully optimized unless you are dealing with millions of records.

```
all_currency_ids = Currency.all.pluck(:id)

Button.eager_load(:extra_price).group('buttons.id').having('count(extra_prices.id) < ?', all_currency_ids.count).each do |button|
  missing_currency_ids = all_currency_ids - button.extra_prices.pluck(:currency_id) 

  missing_currency_ids.each do |missing_currency_id|
    ExtraPrice.create!(currency: Currency.find_by(id: missing_currency_id), product: button)
  end
end
```

---

`Button.eager_load(:extra_price).group('buttons.id').having('count(extra_prices.id) < ?', all_currency_ids.count)` is what gets you the buttons with missing extra prices. This hinges on the fact that each button has an extra price per currency, so I hope I interpreted that correctly.

Comment: `button.extra_prices.create!(currency_id: missing_currency_id)` having to load each `Currency`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Dylan! I will test that as soon as I get to work and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I'm not 100% familiar with Rails 4, only 5 and 6. The underlying SQL principles remain the same regardless and are adaptable.)

You can do this in a single query if your relationships are set up correctly.

```
class Button < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :extra_prices
  has_many :currencies, through: :extra_prices
end

class ExtraPrice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :button
  belongs_to :currency
end

class Currency < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :extra_prices
end
```

I've added a relationship between `Currency` and `ExtraPrice`. This allows us to set up a relationship between `Button` and `Currency` using `has_many :currencies, through: :extra_prices`. Then we can get a Button's Currencies with `button.currencies`.

Now we can do a [left join](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) between `Button` and `ExtraPrice` and `Currency`. A left join, as opposed to the normal inner join, will pick up Buttons that have no ExtraPrices nor Currencies. We can't use Rails's `left_joins`, it will not do the right thing.

```
buttons_missing_currencies = Button
  .includes(:currencies)
  .joins("left join extra_prices ep on ep.button_id = buttons.id")
  .joins("left join currencies c on c.id = ep.currency_id")
  .having("count(c.id) < ?", Currency.count)
  .group("buttons.id")
```

That will give you all the Buttons which lack a Currency in a single, efficient query. `includes(:currencies)` means each Button's Currencies will already be loaded avoiding making [N+1 queries](https://rubyinrails.com/2018/02/20/rails-activeadmin-n-1-query-optimization/).

Now we can look through each button, discover which currencies are missing, and fill them in.

```
all_currencies = Currency.all
buttons_missing_currencies.each do |button|
  missing_currencies = all_currencies - button.currencies

  missing_currencies.each do |missing_currency|
    button.extra_prices.create!(currency: missing_currency)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Schwern! I will test also this solution as soon as I get to work. I also started to added the has_many through and I agree with you that the underlying principles are the same.